# Emit observable result map without waiting for inner observable

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, observable

currently I have following type of code:

```
 obsC$: Observable<Result[T][]> = combineLatest([this.obsA$, this.obsB$]).
 pipe(map(([resultA, resultB]) => ...),
 switchMap(this.serviceA.fetch(resultA).pipe(map((resultD) => ...)))
 )
```

This results in obsC$ having to wait for the result of *this.serviceA.fetch* which I don't want to do since it may take some time. Instead I would like to emit the result once before the switchMap and then emit again after the switchMap has finished. Is there any way to do this with the abovemenioned way? Or do I have to refactor this into separate Observables?

Answer (score 1):

You can just rewrite your `switchMap()` and `merge()` the first result so it's emitted immediately before `this.serviceA.fetch` emits.

```
switchMap(resultA => merge(
  of(resultA),
  this.serviceA.fetch(resultA).pipe(map((resultD) => ...))
))
```

Comment: So far, I have not been able to get this to work. It does now emit the result ASAP, but it will never emit the result of serviceA.fetch.

Comment: This is a simplified example of what you have https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-aqrosk?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, I just can't seem to get it to work. the fetch does not seem to go through properly, or it wont register the result like its supposed to. I think for now, I will just separate them into different Observables, and see if that will work.